# Delete rectangle annotations from Chart

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of signals in a listview. When the user checks one, the values of the signals are being plotted on the chart. Moreover there is a vertical annotation which the user can drag across the graph and see the values for every x value. Each signal has one rectangle annotation that shows the Y value.
My problem is that when the user checks a new signal then the old rectangle annotations do not disappear.
Here is what I mean :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKeGg.png)

Here is my code so far :

```html
 List<RectangleAnnotation> anno = new List<RectangleAnnotation>();
 List<Series> checkedItems = new List<Series>();
 private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.FocusedItem != null)
            {
                double xFactor = 0.03;
                double yFactor = 0.02;
                CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
                
                if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                   
                    anno.Clear();
                    Series s12 = new Series();
                    s12 = chart1.Series.Add((listView1.Items[e.Index].Text).ToString());
                    s12.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    s12.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;  // make the points stand out
                    s12.MarkerSize = 3;
                    checkedItems.Add(s12);
                    
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        anno.Add(new RectangleAnnotation());
                        anno[i].AxisX = CA.AxisX;
                        anno[i].IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
                        anno[i].Width = 20 * xFactor;
                        anno[i].Height = 8 * yFactor;
                        //    VA.Name = "myRect";
                        anno[i].LineColor = Color.Black;
                        anno[i].BackColor = Color.Black;

                        anno[i].AxisY = CA.AxisY;
                        anno[i].Y = -anno[i].Height;
                        //   RA[i].X = VA.X - RA[i].Width / 2;

                        anno[i].Text = "Hello";
                        anno[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;

                        anno[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8f);
                        anno[i].Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 0);
                        chart1.Annotations.Add(anno[i]);
                    }
                    for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)

                    {

                        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
                        dp.SetValueXY(r, values[r, listView1.Items.IndexOf(listView1.Items[e.Index])]);
                        //   chart1.Series[checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString()].Points.Add(dp);
                        s12.Points.AddXY(r, values[r, listView1.Items.IndexOf(listView1.Items[e.Index])]);

                    }
                    }
                    }
                   }
                    private void chart1_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            
            int pt1 = (int)e.NewLocationX;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var signal in checkedItems) {
                
                double val = signal.Points[pt1].YValues[0];
             
                
                foreach (var sim in signal.Points[pt1].YValues)
              {
                    anno[i].Y = sim + 0.5;
                  
              }
                
                
                if (sender == VA) anno[i].X = VA.X - anno[i].Width / 2;
                anno[i].Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", val);
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(anno.Count);
            }
```

I have thought of adding

```html
chart1.Annotations.clear();
```

But it deletes all Annotations including the vertical. I only want to delete the rectangle annotations.

Comment: Well, this `var ras = chart1.Annotations.OfType<RectangleAnnotation>();` will collect only the RectangleAnnotations. But having a Name or a reference may be even better..

Comment: and how could I delete the ras collection of Rectangle annotation, from the char1.Annotation property ?

Comment: `var ras = chart1.Annotations.OfType<RectangleAnnotation>().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < ras.Count; i++)
{
    chart1.Annotations.Remove(ras[i]);
}`

Comment: @nickolas your post is old but did you find any solution? I am also stuck at almost the same issue; how to remove a specific annotation on clicking.